# Using Unity in ASP.NET MVC 4 - Dependency injection error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to inject a dependency into a web api controller using Unity.

I followed

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

closely, however I still get error while instantiating constructor, there there's no parameterless constructor.

Controller:

```
public class ContactsController : ApiController
    {
        IContactsRepository repository;

        public ContactsController(IContactsRepository repository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        public List<ContactDTO> GetAllContacts()
        {
            return repository.GetAllContacts().ToList();
        }
    }
```

Repository interface and class:

```
   public interface IContactsRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<ContactDTO> GetAllContacts();
    }
```

Class:

```
public class ContactsRepository : IContactsRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<ContactDTO> GetAllContacts()
        {
            using (var db = new ContactDatabaseEntities())
            {
                foreach (var contact in db.Contacts)
                {
                    yield return contact.Convert();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I added the line:

```
Bootstrapper.Initialise();
```

to `Global.asax` file, and in `Bootstrapper.cs` I added:

```
container.RegisterType<IContactsRepository, ContactsRepository>();
```

However when i try to access contacts through the url I get the error:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'ContactsController'. Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Unity usually has a class that is called when the application is loaded and is put in the app start? Basically I think you havent set your dependency resolver to use unity... so when the resolver tries to resolve the controller it can't....

Comment: yes, the Bootstrapper.Initialise(); is doing that work

Comment: This is the [package from nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.AspNet.WebApi/3.5.1405-prerelease) that you should be using

Comment: See, there should be no initialise because it is bootstrapped when the application is loaded - not when the global.asax is ran

Comment: Uhm.. I might be underthinking this, but just add an empty, parameterless ctor?

Comment: No @NicklasWinger because then the dependency injection wouldn't work right. In order for this to work, the dependency injection container needs to be hooked up the the internal ASP.NET dependency resolver (Under `GlobalConfiguration.DependencyResolver` I believe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using `ApiController` - for WebAPI dependency injection is implemented in different way. You are referring to a standard MVC way of resolving dependencies, which won't work for WebAPI.

You need to install Unity.WebAPI package to get it working [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/)